# jQuery and the <dialog> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I'm trying to use the new  [HTML element](http://demo.agektmr.com/dialog/). Here's some testing code:

```
<dialog id="addSystemDialog">
    <p>This is a dialog</p>
    <button id='close'>Close dialog</button>
</dialog>
<button id='show'>Show add dialog</button>
```

And in js:

```
var dialog = document.querySelector('dialog');
document.querySelector('#show').onclick = function() {
  dialog.show();
};
document.querySelector('#close').onclick = function() {
  dialog.close();
};
```

If I change the first js line to

```
var dialog = $('dialog');
```

it no longer works. Why?

Comment: Did you include jQuery in your page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.querySelector` returns the **first** match.

jQuery returns an **array** of all matches.

If you use `$('dialog')[0]`, you should get the same result.